# In Auctex, bibtex cannot create reference

Tags: bibtex, natbib, emacs, auctex

Everything goes well in TeXshop.

In Emacs, I went through following steps:

1. `C-c C-c latex`
2. `C-c C-c bibtex`
3. `C-c C-c latex`
4. `C-c C-c latex`

but it keeps saying insolvable reference.

Log file says: `Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.`

Comment: Guess:remove the .aux files and rerun the same steps again

Comment: Also, are you sure that there are not for example some typos means that the references don't work?

Comment: Do any citations appear in the pdf? If so, then it's an isolated problem. If not, then it's a more general problem. It would be helpful to know which it is you have.

Answer (score 1):

Natbib shows on the log which citations were undefined.

> Package natbib warning: Citation xzy on page x undefined on line y

You can check if your citations was written without typos errors.

Otherwise, a solution could be to delete the `.aux` and run another time the sequence: latex, bibtex, latex, latex.